# Ruby: Food Menu that calculates and displays balance of your choice

Tags: ruby

Below is a method that displays a menu using a hash. I can't figure out how to use the input to then calculate and display the balance of the users choice/s. I'm also struggling with the concept of class initialization and how that could help here. Any help very welcome!

```
def product_menu

  product_menu_hash = {
                        "Coffee"               =>  4.00,
                        "Soft Drink"           =>  4.00,
                        "Sandwich (Meat)"      =>  9.50,
                        "Sandwich (Veg)"       =>  8.00,
                        "Coffee Maker"         => 50.00,
                        "Bag of Coffee (250g)" => 13.25,
                      }

  puts "COFFEE SHOP"

  product_menu_hash.each_with_index do |(item, price), index|
    puts "#{index + 1} #{item} = $#{price}"
    input = gets.chomp
  end
end
```

Comment: What will the user input be will it be menu item number or Item name? You can use the `initialize` method to initialize any attribute value whenever a new instance is created.

Comment: how does  a user exit out of this method?

Comment: @sahil the user would input menu choice number so for example coffee would be 1 and soft drink would be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The user is the shop assistant and I imagined them just entering the
>   menu choice e.g. 1 for Coffee or 2 for soft drink etc then the price
>   being calculated from there. Is there a way to do this?

Based on your last comment, a second answer would be

```
tot = 0
 product_menu_hash = {
"Coffee" => 4.00,
"Soft Drink" => 4.00,
"Sandwich (Meat)" => 9.50,
"Sandwich (Veg)" => 8.00,
"Coffee Maker" => 50.00,
"Bag of Coffee (250g)" => 13.25,
  }
 product_choice = {}

product_menu_hash.each_with_index do |(item,  price), index|
     product_choice[index+1]=item
    puts "#{index + 1} #{item} = $#{price}"
end
puts 'x to exit, p to print total   ' 
choice = gets.chomp
while choice != 'x' do
    if choice == 'p' then
        puts 'total: ', tot
    else
        puts product_choice[choice.to_i],product_menu_hash[product_choice[choice.to_i]]
        tot += product_menu_hash[product_choice[choice.to_i]]
    end
    choice = gets.chomp
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If users enter quantities of items as integers

```
tot = 0
 product_menu_hash = {
"Coffee" => 4.00,
"Soft Drink" => 4.00,
"Sandwich (Meat)" => 9.50,
"Sandwich (Veg)" => 8.00,
"Coffee Maker" => 50.00,
"Bag of Coffee (250g)" => 13.25,
  }

  puts "COFFEE SHOP"
  product_menu_hash.each_with_index do |(item,  price), index|

  puts "#{index + 1} #{item} = $#{price}"

  input = gets.chomp
  totpar = input.to_i * price
  puts totpar
  tot += totpar
end
puts 'total: ', tot
```

Comment: thanks for helping. The user is the shop assistant and I imagined them just entering the menu choice e.g.  1 for Coffee or 2 for soft drink etc then the price being calculated from there. Is there a way to do this?